# angularjs: checking url location change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm watching the `$locationChangeSuccess` event. I need a clean way to check whether the URL has changed or if only the parameters have changed. I could compare the 'next' and 'current' parameters, but maybe there's a function doing that already  ?

Comment: i think there is not existing function to do such comparison

Answer (score 0):

Set up a custom watch:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $location) {
  // Watch parameters...
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $location.search();
  }, function(newParams, oldParams) {
    console.log(newParams);
    console.log(oldParams);
  }, true);
}
```

Note the third argument `true` passed to `$scope.$watch()`; important to ensure the watch value, in this case an object, is watched deeply for changes (and not referentially).